# "The pipe is being closed" error when using GeoLocator in Windows Store App(Windows 8.1)?

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, bing-maps

I am working in Windows 8.1 app and I am finding the current location of the user using below mentioned code. Now when I run my app in Tablet using Cellular network the app crashes but it works fine on Wifi. Can someone suggest a solution for this?

```
            geolocator = new Geolocator();
            geolocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.Default;
            geolocator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 1000;
            geolocator.MovementThreshold = 5;
            geolocator.ReportInterval = 500;
            try
            {
                Geoposition mygeoPosition = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
            }
            catch(UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
            {
                UserMessageUtil.ShowMessage("Location is disabled in Settings");
                await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings-location:"));
            }
            geolocator.PositionChanged += geolocator_PositionChanged;
```

I always check in Laptop Machine so I didn't face this issue in past but now I have a tablet with both 3G and WIFI connectivity and when I run the app in tablet and try to get the current location, the error comes.

**Update**

I also sometimes get *The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007139F)* error on line

```
Geoposition mygeoPosition = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
```

I get both these error when I am connected on a **Cellular network**

Answer (score 2):

These are both very low-level Windows error codes.  Whatever fails is either very far removed from your code, roughly the device driver level.  Or it is an error code that was re-used by intermediary software layers, a very common crime in WinRT.  You do have to keep in mind that lots and lots of things can go wrong in networking and you don't always get a fantastic diagnostic.  Well, almost never.

"The pipe is being closed" is ERROR_NO_DATA.  That error identifier is pretty likely to be more representative than the message.

"The group or resource is not in the correct state" is ERROR_INVALID_STATE.  Again that identifier quacks more sensibly than the message.

My call: your cellular network connection is just flaky.  Either because the radio is spotty or because there's crappy anti-malware in between.  You can eliminate the latter easily enough.  But the former is always going to happen on *somebody's* machine.  So do write your code to be resilient to those kind of networking mishaps, do *not* just catch UnauthorizedAccessException.  Write another catch for Exception and display a "We're sorry, service temporarily unavailable" style message.  Maybe you can band-aid it by memorizing the previous location, as long as the user knows.

Comment: Thanks Hans. Is it possible that if device doesn’t have GPS sensors or GPS sensor is disabled then this errors may have occurred?

Comment: Yes, very likely.  If it has a functioning GPS sensor then it doesn't need any help.

Answer (score 1):

Start off by using a larger movement threshold. Most GPS devices only have an accuracy of 15 meters. Setting the movement threshold to 5 could be too small and cause issue.

Also look at using one of the position accuracy enumerators:

geolocator.DesiredAccuracy =
Windows.Devices.Geolocation.PositionAccuracy.high;

Comment: @rbrunditt I tried adding both parameters but still it gave me error. Is it possible that as I am using free Bing Map key it is causing issue?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Bing Maps. The Geolocation API is a core Windows Phone library that is not related to Bing Maps.